# Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: Error 404 Not Found]

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to index a model in Solr with django-haystack, but it returns me the following error(when using rebuild_index or update_index) :

```
Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: Error 404 Not Found]
```

This is search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from haystack.indexes import SearchIndex
from jobpost.models import *



class JobIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    post_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='post_type')
    location = indexes.CharField(model_attr='location')
    job_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_type')
    company_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='company_name')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return jobpost

    def index_queryset(self,**kwargs):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

haystack connection:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',

        'SITECONF': 'jobpost.search_sites'
    },
}
```

I have generated schema.xml many times restarted solr..placed it in solr/conf..don't know what's the isuue

Comment: Is it started and you can browse to the solr server by visiting http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr ?

Comment: Check the solr logs and post what the error is, please

Comment: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=jobpost.jobpost.1] unknown field 'django_id'

Comment: Your schema.xml is wrong. It's lacking the field `django_id`. Could you post your schema.xml, please? You probably have generated the schema but not copied it into your Solr installation.

Comment: using another version of solr solved it

Answer (score 5):

As specified [in settings docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html) you need to specify the url to your core. Seems like you've missed the core in your URL. You need to create a core and the url should look like this:

```
'URL': 'http://localhost:9001/solr/default',
```

Comment: my old code didn't need to specify the last `solr/default`, but after updating a few things, I need to use the full url you specified.  Not sure which specific version upgrade caused it.

Comment: I have even specified the core then also it is not working