# django-haystack: Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: Error 404 Not Found]

Tags: solr, django-haystack, pysolr

I'm using django-haystack (v 2.3.1) with solr (v 5.0.0) and pysolr (v 3.0.0). I've been following the [tutorial](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#solr), and have set up similar `myapp/search_indexes.py` and `search/indexes/myapp/mymodel_text.txt` files.

`./manage.py build_solr_schema > schema.xml` works fine, and I have copied this to $SOLR_HOME/conf/schema.xml.

The problem occurs when I try `./manage.py rebuild_index`. First, I'm asked to confirm:

> WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
>   Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
>   Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Then, it fails:

> Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
>   Failed to clear Solr index: [Reason: Error 404 Not Found]
>   All documents removed.
>   Indexing 6 stories
>   Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: Error 404 Not Found]

My connection settings are:

```
#settings.py
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
    },
}
```

If I navigate to this url I **can** see the solr admin page. I have made sure that port 8983 is open for solr (as well as 8000 for the Django development server).

I feel that I may not have provided enough connection information, but what else is there to check?

**UPDATE**:
Although I solved this problem there were more to come, which were *all* fixed by **using solr (v.4.7.0)** instead, as django-haystack isn't ready for solr 5 (there was an issue related to this but I can no longer find it on [github](https://github.com/toastdriven/pysolr/issues).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to user366722 for suggesting to specify the core in the settings. However, I had neglected an even more fundamental step of *creating* the core!

**Solution:**
Create the core, specifying the name of the core (e.g. 'default') and the port (e.g. 8983):

> `$bin/solr create_core -c default -p 8983`

Then, just specify the name of the core (e.g. 'default') in your haystack URL settings:

```
#settings.py
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/default',
    },
}
```

**Done!**

Now, I get

> Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
>   All documents removed.
>   Indexing 3 stories

**UPDATE**:
At the time of writing, I also switched to solr 4.7.0 to make it work, as haystack wasn't ready for solr 5.x

Comment: bin/solr create_core -c default -p 8983
can u tell me which bin ?! Thanks

Comment: which bin depends on where you installed it

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29833997/366722
You need to specify the core in your URL

Comment: Which version of solr were you using? Apparently the [the structure of the solr.xml file has changed](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%204.4%20and%20beyond): "In a nutshell, [as of solr v5.0] <cores> and <core> have been replaced by auto-discovering cores." As I gave up at the time, I'm not sure if django-haystack was able to produce a compatible solr.xml file for v5 of solr (i.e. without <cores>).

Comment: That's correct. I am using 5.1.0 and setting it up using an old documentation of haystack that uses 4.x.